# Need Help on Writing trigger on Junction Object

Tags: trigger

I have a Junction object called "LOCATION JUNCTION", and
it has two master-detail relationships to Opportunity and Location

When I create new junction object records like

1. name1 opp1 loca1
2. name2 opp2 loca1

The system should throw an error like

`"please select different location"`

(FOR one account if  opp1 is having location1 then opp2 should not take location1)
(Opportunities under same account should not have same location)
How should I write a trigger on this junction object.
Please suggest.
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Should this be part of trigger or validation rules ?

Comment: Part of Trigger  karthik

Comment: I have updated my ans please try that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming junction object name is `LocationJunction__c` and location field name is `Location__c`.

> **Following code will only process one record properly.** Click to [Bulkify your
>   trigger](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice%3A_Bulkify_Your_Code)

```
trigger LocationJunctionTrigger on LocationJunction__c (after insert,after Update)
{
    if(trigger.isAfter && (trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate))
    {
        List<LocationJunction__c> currentList = [SELECT Id,Location__c,Opportunity__r.AccountId from LocationJunction__c WHERE Location__c=:trigger.new[0].Location__c AND Id IN : trigger.new];
        List<LocationJunction__c> existingList = [SELECT Id,Location__c,Opportunity__r.AccountId from LocationJunction__c WHERE Location__c=:trigger.new[0].Location__c AND Id Not IN : trigger.new];

        for(LocationJunction__c currentLocation : currentList)
        {
            for(LocationJunction__c existingLocation : existingList)
                if(existingLocation.Opportunity__r.AccountId == currentLocation.Opportunity__r.AccountId)
                    trigger.new[0].adderror('Please select different location');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Peeyush,  it should check for opportunity1 and opportunity2 which are related to same Account.

Comment: Ok i will update my answer

Comment: Please try this code

Comment: Thank you very much Peeyush, its working for this requirement. 
For the same requirement if we have opp2 startdate is BETWEEN opp1 startdate and closedate then the location should not be same as opp1 for opp2 (location should be different).
if opp2 startdate is NOT BETWEEN opp1 startdate and closedate then the location can be anything.
can you please advice.

Comment: In both query you should add Opportunity__r.StartDate and end date.
Now you put one more condition in inner for loop -> If((existing condition)&&(currentLocation.Opportunity__r.StartDate>=existingLocation.Opportunity__r.StartDate&&currentLocation.Opportunity__r.StartDate<=existingLocation.Opportunity__r.endDate))

Comment: Thanks Peeyush. It is working. but when i am displaying error with currentLocation.Location__c.adderror('Please select different location'); it is giving error like "sobject row does not allow errors:"

Comment: Use currentLocation.adderror('Please select different location')

Comment: I Have used that one as well,but same error.

Comment: Can you post another question with error and and your code

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code

```
trigger LocationJunctionCRUD on LocationJunction__c (before insert) 
{

 List<Id> lstOpportunity= new List<Id>();

  Map<Id,Id> mapOppLoc= new Map<Id,Id>();
    for(LocationJunction__c  locationJunction: Trigger.new){
        lstOpportunity.add(locationJunction.Opportunity__c);
        mapOppLoc.put(locationJunction.Opportunity__c,locationJunction.Location__c );
    }


if(lstOpportunity != null && lstOpportunity.size()>0){

   List<LocationJunction__c> lstlocationJunction= [Select id,Opportunity__c,Location__c from LocationJunction__c
                                     where Opportunity__c in :lstOpportunity];

 if(lstlocationJunction!= null && lstlocationJunction.size()>0){    
    for(LocationJunction__c locationJunction:lstlocationJunction){

 if(locationJunction.Location__c == mapOppCamp.get(locationJunction.Opportunity__c))
{
              trigger.new[0].adderror('This Location already exist in other record');

  }

}

 }                         

 } 

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Martin, I guess this will make any Opportunity with same location throws error. I need somethiing like "Opportunities under same account should not have same location"..