# SObject row does not allow errors

Tags: trigger

If I use `adderror` as below I get the following error. How do I fix it?

> SObject row does not allow errors

```
trigger LocationJunctionTrigger on Location_Junction__c (After insert,After Update)
{
    set<id> locid =new set<id>();
    set<id> junid =new set<id>();
    for(Location_Junction__c jun:trigger.new){

        locid.add(jun.location__c);
        junid.add(jun.id);
    }
    if(trigger.isAfter && (trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate))
    {
        list<Location_Junction__c> currentList = [SELECT Id,Location__c,Opportunity__r.Start_Date__c,Opportunity__r.AccountId from Location_Junction__c WHERE Location__c IN :locid AND Id IN : junid];
        list<Location_Junction__c> existingList = [SELECT Id,Location__c,Opportunity__r.Start_Date__c,Opportunity__r.closedate,Opportunity__r.AccountId from Location_Junction__c WHERE Location__c IN :locid AND Id Not IN : junid];

        for(Location_Junction__c currentLocation :currentList)
        {
            for(Location_Junction__c existingLocation :existingList){
    if( existingLocation.Opportunity__r.AccountId == currentLocation.Opportunity__r.AccountId && currentLocation.Opportunity__r.Start_Date__c < existingLocation.Opportunity__r.closedate && currentLocation.Opportunity__r.Start_Date__c > existingLocation.Opportunity__r.Start_Date__c)

              currentLocation.Location__c.adderror('Please select different location');
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ratan, I have also tried using currentLocation.adderror('Please select different location'); same error is coming.  if i use trigger.new[0].adderror('Please select different location');  then its working fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This is the solution for the above post**

```
Map<id,Location_junction__C> Mapjun = Trigger.newmap;
Mapjun.get(currentLocation.id).Location__c.adderror('Please select different location');
```

Comment: is it an answer?... seems like it is.

Comment: @Ratan  yes, it is an answer.

Comment: Pls add a comment in your post like this is working.. like else any one will be confuse and will give you downvote.

Answer (score 4):

.addError can be called on Trigger.new in before/after insert and before/after update triggers, and on Trigger.old in before delete List. You can't add this to any other sObject that is why error is saying SObject row does not allow error.

So in your case you can add this to **Location_Junction__c**

Comment: Hi Himanshu, I was getting "Variable does not exist: Location_Junction__c "

Comment: when I say Location_Junction__c it is Trigger.new list.

Comment: when i use  trigger.new[0]. Location__c.adderror('Please select different location'); its is showing error message like "Please select different location (Related field: Location)". can't i show the message next to the Location Field ?

Comment: inside trigger you can only add error to Trigger.new[0]

Comment: Not quite right... You can call it on the old values in a `delete` trigger.

Comment: yah I forgot to mention that as this question was only related to insert/update context. thanks for pointing out @AdrianLarson

Comment: Can it not be called on undelete?

Comment: Himanshu -- `addError()` can be used in before/after insert/update and before delete - see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_exceptions.htm?search_text=addError cc: @AdrianLarson

Comment: @crop1645 yah I agree. I have already added that in answer. did I missed anything ?

Comment: Himanshu -- you stated only in 'before' triggers, not also 'after' triggers

Answer (score 1):

You can use the addError method for only those records that are avaliable in Trigger Context. You are calling the addError on a field instead of sObject. Change the line to

> provided currentLocation is part of the trigger context

```
 currentLocation.adderror('Please select different location');
```

You are traversing through `existingList` and you have populated with non trigger context records.

```
for(Location_Junction__c jun:trigger.new){

        locid.add(jun.location__c);
        junid.add(jun.id);
    }

    list<Location_Junction__c> existingList = [SELECT Id,Location__c,Opportunity__r.Start_Date__c,Opportunity__r.closedate,Opportunity__r.AccountId from Location_Junction__c WHERE Location__c IN :locid AND Id Not IN : junid];
```

What is the business logic here ? You want to throw errors for records which are not in trigger context ?

Comment: Thanks Bennie, I was getting "Variable does not exist: Location_Junction__c "

Comment: @MaytheForcebewithyou see my updated post

Comment: I tried existingLocation.adderror('Please select different location'); and currentLocation.adderror('Please select different location'); both giving same error.

Comment: @Bennie  Please check this http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/110753/need-help-on-writing-trigger-on-junction-object/110759#110759

Comment: @MaytheForcebewithyou see updated post. `currentLocation.adderror('Please select different location');`

Comment: @bennie , No Luck

Comment: @MaytheForcebewithyou what's the error ?